# AFx Library library exception: File: ..\..\Dataset2\Dataset2.dataset cannot be found. . ( Error 1000 )

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a simple Azure Machine Learning experiment, with two input blocks ("Enter Data Manually") that pass their input to an "Execute R Script" block that binds the two inputs.

When the two input values are the same, I get an AFx Library exception FileNotFound. When the two input values are different, everything works fine.

Here is the R code and the experiment outline.

```
d1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame
d2 <- maml.mapInputPort(2) # class: data.frame

print(d1)
print(class(d1))

print(d2)
print(class(d2))
```

[image]

The error I get when I set the same input data in the two input blocks, in more detail is the following:

```
    [Critical]     Error: Error 1000: AFx Library library exception: File: ..\..\Dataset2\Dataset2.dataset cannot be found.
    [Critical]     {"InputParameters":{"DataTable":[{"Rows":2,"Columns":1,"estimatedSize":12001280,"ColumnTypes":
{"System.Int32":1},"IsComplete":true,"Statistics":
{"0":[1.5,1.5,1.0,2.0,0.70710678118654757,2.0,0.0]}}]},"OutputParameters":
[],"ModuleType":"LanguageWorker","ModuleVersion":" 
Version=6.0.0.0","AdditionalModuleInfo":"LanguageWorker, Version=6.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca;
Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.LanguageWorker.LanguageWorkerClientRS;
RunRSNR","Errors":"Microsoft.Analytics.Exceptions.ErrorMapping+ModuleException: 
Error 1000: AFx Library library exception: File: ..\\..\\Dataset2
\\Dataset2.dataset cannot be found. ---> 
Microsoft.Numerics.AFxLibraryFileNotFoundException: File: ..\\..\\Dataset2
\\Dataset2.dataset cannot be found.\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Analytics.IO.Local.DataTableReader..ctor(String filePath)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.DllModuleHost.DataLab.Handlers.DataTableDatasetHandler.H
andleArgumentString(String argument, ParameterInfo paramInfo)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.DllModuleHost.ParameterArgumentBinder.InitializeParamete
rValues(MethodInfo method, Dictionary`2 moduleDescription)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.DllModuleHost.DllModuleMethod.Execute(Dictionary`2 
moduleDescription)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.MetaAnalytics.DllModuleHost.Program.Main(String[] args)\r\n   --- End 
of inner exception stack trace ---","Warnings":[],"Duration":"00:00:00.5755180"}
    Module finished after a runtime of 00:00:01.4722617 with exit code -2
    Module failed due to negative exit code of -2
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated, Flo.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the R code referencing the second dataset because you only have one input dataset.

Comment: Could you please extend on your answer? As it is, it does not explain the error. The two input fields are actually filled by other means. Sometimes they are equal, sometimes not. When they are equal I get an error in the experiment.